# FileMaker Plugin Issue

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcodebuild, filemaker

I am compiling a plugin for FileMaker using Xcode.

I get no errors or warnings, and my 'target' is my FM/Extensions folder. Everything works well on my computer. It installs and then when I open FileMaker/Preferences/Plugin it is listed like it should be.

Problem: I copied the project to another computer and I get the same results except that when I look in the FM/Preferences/Plugin folder it does not show up.

Can anyone please help me brainstorm? I don't know what the issue could be. I did look at permissions already.

Thanks

Comment: Are both macs on intel architecture?

Comment: Yes, that's the weird thing. We have basically the same machine. I think maybe the framework has something to do with it.... I might try copying over the framework files from my computer to the other machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary Solution:

Put the plugin in a package using PackageMaker. I ran the package and it worked.....I guess just dragging the plugin into the extensions folder doesn't work. Or running the xcode for that matter.

Thanks!